# Multipeer connectivity using Titianium

Tags: javascript, ios7, titanium, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to implement the multipeer connectivity recently launched by Apple using Titanium.I did find a module from [Logical Labs](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/8365#!overview).

But the documentation provided by them is not clear enough to get me started, neither did I get any demo apps or examaple apps created by them in the same.

Can anybody please help me in finding if there is any sample app as such in titanium that I can use to get my work started? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else is stuck with the same issue which I was,the example application is there within the module of Logical Labs.

All you need to do is download the module from logical labs and locate the example application within the zip file.

Load the example app in your titanium IDE and this should be it for making it run. 
Thanks